# Each memeber of a list of floats in a list is smaller than previous

Tags: algorithm, elixir

I have a long list (1000+) of numbers that is mix of integers and floats (so 1.3 and 2.5 but also 3 or 5).

Generally, they should be following the decreasing pattern so from the biggest to the lowest.

But there are some black sheeps that break this rule and I want to find them.

Here is part of my list:

```
list = [100.242, 95, 94.3, 96, 65.5, 67.7, 51.25, 43, 23.99] # 96 and 67.7 are bad actors
```

Now, I need to make a function that will pick out those bad numbers and put them in a list I can print.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I don't know elixir but here are 2 ideas: loop over the list from `1..n`. Compare element at `i` with element at `i-1` and if it breaks the rule, push it to the result list. Second idea is to create a lazy list of tuples made of elements `i` and `i-1` and compare them. This can be done using `zip`.

Comment: I am not familiar with elixir at all, but a general algorithm might involve moving iterating a variable `idx` from left to right, along with a stack of indices `st` seen on the left (contains potentially good actors). Check `list[idx]` against the element pointed to by `list[st.top()]`; if the stack is empty or the `list[idx] < list[st.top()]`, then push `idx` onto the stack. Otherwise, `list[st.top()]` is for sure a bad actor and should be popped. The nice thing about this algorithm is that it can handle consecutive bad numbers (i.e `list = [3,1,2,2.5] => 1, 2`) and does so in linear time.

Comment: What have you tried?  Generally around here you’re expected to show your work and explain where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) is always to the rescue in these kinds of problems

```elixir
Enum.reduce(list, {[], []}, fn
  e, {[], []} -> {[e], []}
  e, {[h|t], ko} when e > h -> {[h|t], [e|ko]}
  e, {ok, ko} -> {[e|ok], ko}
end)
#⇒ {[23.99, 43, 51.25, 65.5, 94.3, 95, 100.242], [67.7, 96]}
```

Plain recursion would also work perfectly.

Comment: Hmm, I have tried it with this list `list = [ 1, 1.75, 2, 1.25, 17, 1.10 ]` and the output is `{[1], [1.1, 17, 1.25, 2, 1.75]}` instead of expected `{[1, 1.75, 2, 17], [1.25, 1.10]}`. Any idea how to get the expected output?

Comment: Your initial list was decreaing. The one you tried is increasing. Change > to < in the guard, obviously.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Obviously ;)